# Error : Expected expression before 'DATA /* : typedef struct DATA DATA */

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, linked-list, typedef

I don't know what's the problem here my code. I read some questions of others that had the same problem , but I didn't found an answer.
When I try to compile I get this errors :

> ||In function 'main':|
>
> |35|error: expected expression before 'DATA'|
>
> ||In function 'lecture_data':|
>
> |59|error: expected expression before 'DATA'|
>
> ||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I want also to know what should I do , And what should I don't in this code if there is other problems .

**The Code :**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define V 20

    /* Structure */

    typedef struct DATA{
        char* NomP;
        char* NomA;
        int iNbr;
        int iPix;
        struct DATA *Next;
    }DATA;

    /* --------- */

    void* MALLOC(size_t nombre);
    int lecture_data(FILE *fs,DATA* Data,DATA* ROOT);
    void print_data(DATA* data,int len);

    int main(void)
    {
        char FileName[V];
        puts("Data file ? : ");
        gets(FileName);

        FILE* fs = fopen(FileName,"r");
        if( fs == NULL )
        {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        DATA *HEAD = MALLOC(sizeof DATA);
        DATA *D_Store;
        int len = lecture_data(fs,D_Store,HEAD);
        print_data(D_Store,len);
        return 0;
    }

    int lecture_data(FILE *fs,DATA *Data,DATA *ROOT)
    {
        char cNom[V],cArticle[V];
        int iNombre,iPrix;
        int eofs=0;int i=0;

        while(!eofs)
        {
            fscanf(fs,"%s %s %d %d",cNom,cArticle,&iNombre,&iPrix);
            Data->iNbr=iNombre;
            Data->iPix=iPrix;
            Data->NomA = MALLOC(strlen(cArticle)+1);
            Data->NomP = MALLOC(strlen(cNom)+1);
            strcpy(Data->NomA,cArticle);
            strcpy(Data->NomP,cNom);
            if( i==0 )
            {
                Data -> Next = MALLOC(sizeof DATA);
                ROOT = Data ;
            }
            DATA *Ptr = ROOT ;
            while( Ptr -> Next != NULL )
            {
                Ptr = ROOT -> Next;
            }
            Data -> Next = NULL ;
            Ptr -> Next = Data ;

            fprintf(stdout,"Data : N.%d: %s %s %d$\n",i,cNom,cArticle,iNombre*iPrix);
            i++;
            eofs = feof(fs) ;

            if(ferror(fs))
            {
                perror("Error ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        fclose(fs);
        return i;
    }

    void* MALLOC(size_t nombre)
    {
        void *MEMEORY = malloc(nombre);
        if(NULL == MEMEORY )
        {
            perror("Error ");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return MEMEORY;
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof DATA` should be `sizeof( DATA )` Parentheses needed to type name in `sizeof`

Comment: I understand thanks ; sizeof unary_xpression ; or sizeof (type) is the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
DATA *HEAD = MALLOC( sizeof( DATA ) );
```

instead of

```
DATA *HEAD = MALLOC(sizeof DATA);
```

The sizeof operator is defined the following way

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

As you see the type name shall be enclosed in parentheses.

From the C Standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators )

> 2 The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
>   may be an expression **or the parenthesized name of a type**.

Take into account that if `e` is an expression then `( e )` is also an expression. Therefore for expressions you may write either

```
sizeof e
```

or

```
sizeof( e )
```

And an identifier of a variable also forms an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
DATA *HEAD = MALLOC(sizeof DATA);
```

to

```
DATA *HEAD = MALLOC(sizeof (DATA));
```

Type-name operands to `sizeof` operator have to be parenthesized.

Comment: It's my problem , I read that I should not parenthesize when it's not a basic type ( int , char .. ) , My question now is : when should I parenthesize and when not ?

Comment: `sizeof` accepts either expression or type-name operands.  For expressions the parentheses are optional (e.g., `sizeof 42` or `sizeof (42)`) and for type-name they are required (e..g,`sizeof (int)`).